# Web Service - Relating Request And Response

Tags: web-services, security, tcp, digital-signature, computer-forensics

In a web service (web api) setting, what is the way to prove that a digitally signed response is related to the particular request. For example, I send some parameters and the response returns "true" or "false" but I want to prove that the response is linked to the parameters that I sent. The only way I can think of is that the response should include these parameters. Is there another option?

Answer (score 0):

You have to link the request to the response including the request itself (or the main parts) or simply a hash of the URL and parameters. For example `SHA256 (path +param1 + params2 + param3)` depending on the data you want to preserve. The digital signature protects the integrity of the response in both cases.

If you include a hash in response you need also to store the request, or at least the parameters of the request, to be able to verify that the hash corresponds to the parameters sent. Include also a identifier to link the request and response in an easy way